# loop to assign new objects names based on list in r

Tags: r, xml, assign

I'm new in reading xml files and I'm stuck trying to assign new objects names of the environment after convert them to a list.

I read 35 files of a directory and parsed them with `xmlParse`, of `XML` package. Them, I converted them into a list.

```
for(i in dir()){
  assign(i, xmlParse(i))}

for(i in ls()){
  assign(i, xmlToList(i))
}

rm(i)
```

all files are names like that:

```
ls()

 [1] "en_product3_146.xml" "en_product3_147.xml" "en_product3_148.xml" "en_product3_149.xml"
 [5] "en_product3_150.xml" "en_product3_152.xml" "en_product3_156.xml" "en_product3_181.xml"
 [9] "en_product3_182.xml" "en_product3_183.xml" "en_product3_184.xml" "en_product3_185.xml"
[13] "en_product3_186.xml" "en_product3_187.xml" "en_product3_188.xml" "en_product3_189.xml"
[17] "en_product3_193.xml" "en_product3_194.xml" "en_product3_195.xml" "en_product3_196.xml"
[21] "en_product3_197.xml" "en_product3_198.xml" "en_product3_199.xml" "en_product3_200.xml"
[25] "en_product3_201.xml" "en_product3_202.xml" "en_product3_203.xml" "en_product3_204.xml"
[29] "en_product3_205.xml" "en_product3_209.xml" "en_product3_212.xml" "en_product3_216.xml"
[33] "en_product3_229.xml" "en_product3_231.xml" "en_product3_233.xml"
```

All these files have the same structure, and i want to replace the object name to a value of these list.
The path is that:

```
    head(en_product3_150.xml$DisorderList$Disorder$ClassificationNodeList$ClassificationNode$ClassificationNodeChildList[5]$ClassificationNode$Disorder$Name$text)

[1] "Disorder of carbohydrate metabolism"

head(en_product3_147.xml$DisorderList$Disorder$ClassificationNodeList$ClassificationNode$ClassificationNodeChildList[5]$ClassificationNode$Disorder$Name$text)

[1] "Digestive tract malformation"
```

I'm having some trouble trying to `assign` a new name, like the code above, but I not suceed.

```
for(i in ls()){
assign(paste0(i,"$DisorderList$Disorder$ClassificationNodeList$ClassificationNode$ClassificationNodeChildList[5]$ClassificationNode$Disorder$Name$text"), i)}
```

I would be very gratefull with some tips. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to use `get()` first to access the object in your environment, create the name of the new object, then use `assign()` to assign.

```
rm(list = ls())

# put some things in the environment
x <- list(a = "hello", b = "world")
y <- list(a = "hola", b = "mundo")
z <- list(a = "bonjour", b = "monde")

# loop through environment objects; 
# use get() to access, and assign() to put back 
for (i in ls()) {
  temp <- get(i)
  new_name <- temp$a
  assign(new_name, temp)
  rm(i, temp) # removes object i, not the object whose name is stored in i
}

ls()
```

Note that with this code, you'll have two objects with different names but same content.

Comment: thank you so much! i just add a rm with "en_product" pattern to remove the old files, so, it worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Reconsider saving separate *many* objects flooding your global environment. Instead store similar structured objects in a list for indexable search and consistent processing. So instead of 35 objects to manage, you only manage **one** object of 35 elements.

For such structures built from iterative processing, consider `lapply` or it's wrapper `sapply` since it retains names. The *apply* family are hidden loops that returns an object(s) with equal length as its input:

```
xmls <- sapply(dir(), function(f) {
    x <- xmlParse(f)
    lst <- xmlToList(x)

    t <- (lst$DisorderList
             $Disorder
             $ClassificationNodeList
             $ClassificationNode
             $ClassificationNodeChildList[5]
             $ClassificationNode
             $Disorder
             $Name
             $text)

    return(t)
}, simplify = FALSE)


# OUTPUT ELEMENTS BY NAME
xmls$en_product3_146.xml
xmls$en_product3_147.xml
xmls$en_product3_148.xml
...
```

Comment: that was gold! as a beginner in R, I have this object problem hahaha but i'll apply your tip and improve my codes. thank you!